# Adding an image to an existing PDF, java

Tags: java, javafx, itext

I have been trying to add an image to a PDF document using iText 7.

The function I have created to add the image takes a ImageData type and then adds it to a rectangle on a canvas and add that to a PDF. however, I keep getting the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

and then

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: pdf.pdf (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

The function code is:

```
protected void ExportToPdf(ImageData img) throws IOException {
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("pdf.pdf"), new PdfWriter("pdf.pdf"));

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());

PageSize ps = PageSize.A4;

Rectangle page = new Rectangle(ps.getWidth(),ps.getHeight());

canvas.addImage(img, page, true);

pdfDoc.close();
```

`

And my main is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { //adds values to maps for the program to use


    //starts PDF writer
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("pdf.pdf");
    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    // Initialize document
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    pdf.addNewPage();

    document.close();
    writer.close();
    pdf.close();
```

The full program takes a scene and converts it into an image and then feeds it into the function to be added to the PDF. The code for that is:

```
WritableImage img = new WritableImage(1000, 700);
scene.snapshot(img);
RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);
ImageData imgData = ImageDataFactory.create(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null), null);
ExportToPdf(imgData);
```

Any help would be amazing, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is already here

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("pdf.pdf"), new PdfWriter("pdf.pdf"));
```

Itext does not support writing to the same file you are reading from. Simply instead write to a temporary file and replace the original file with it when finished.